# BASH - Function returns wrong value

Tags: bash, shell

It has been awhile since I scripted. I was never good to begin with..

I am working on a script that would test an oracle DB connection.

```
testDB() {
    [[ $(tnsping $tnsName | grep -c WRONG)==1 ]] && return 1
    return 0
}

testDB
status="${?}"
echo "Status value= " $status
```

I am expecting a 0 value from my echo but somehow my status is showing 1 in my echo.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT2:

My original code was:

```
testDB() {
    [[ $(tnsping $tnsName | grep -c OK) -eq 1 ]] && return 1
    return 0
}
```

my $tnsName contains a correct value and the grep count would be 1, yet my functions returns 0.

Comment: Your intension with `[[ $(tnsping $tnsName | grep -c WRONG)==1 ]] && return 1` is not very clear.

Comment: basically, i am hoping to grep -c OK from the tnsping. the count will be 1 if the tnsping is successful. the TNSPING should not contain any word called WRONG in the result.. so the count would be 0.

Comment: @sjsam The immediate problem the OP wa having was the lack of whitespace around the equals signs, wasn't it? Your edit turns it into a different question; code edits in questions are always problematic - is the problem still reproducible after your change?

Comment: @tripleee : Hmm,, Indeed i didn't notice that.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables not needed, nor `grep -c`.  Just use `grep -q` (no output), to return a true/false flag:

```
testDB() {
    tnsping $tnsName | grep -q OK
    }

testDB
echo "Status value= " $?
```

Comment: The `-q` option is handy ++

Comment: tried [[ $(tnsping $tnsName | grep -q WRONG) ]] && return 1 || return 0 . Function still returns 1/true even when it should be false

Comment: The `[[` is completely superfluous. You want simply `testDB` or in longhand `if tnsping "$tnsName" | grep -q OK; then mumble; else dont; fi`

Comment: @Kyle, with a util that's designed to return true and false exit codes, logic like `... && return1 || return 0` is *always* unnecessary.  Suppose a util returns *true/false*, (e.g. `echo foo | grep -q bar && echo yes || echo no`), and you need *false/true*, just prefix a `!` (logical *not*) where needed, (e.g. `! echo foo | grep -q bar && echo yes || echo no`).

Answer (score 0):

Its the second line `&&`. It is a way to execute multiple statements together and works like the Boolean "and" in many other languages. This instructs the bash session to execute both the compound test command and the `return 1` statement together.

I understand your intention is to return 1 is the test is true else return 0. If thats the case just write it that way.

`testDB() {
    if [[ $(tnsping $tnsName | grep -c WRONG)==1 ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}`

I hope that helps.